# CUDA: Best number of pixel computed per thread (grayscale)

Tags: image-processing, cuda, nvidia

I'm working on a program to convert an image in grayscale. I'm using the CImg library. I have to read for each pixel, the 3 values R-G-B, calculate the corresponding gray value and store the gray pixel on the output image. I'm working with an **NVIDIA GTX 480**. Some details about the card:

- Microarchitecture: **Fermi**
- Compute capability (version): **2.0**
- Cores per SM (warp size): **32**
- Streaming Multiprocessors: **15**
- Maximum number of resident warps per multiprocessor: **48**
- Maximum amount of shared memory per multiprocessor: **48KB**
- Maximum number of resident threads per multiprocessor: **1536**
- Number of 32-bit registers per multiprocessor: **32K**

I'm using a square grid with blocks of 256 threads.
This program can have as input images of different sizes (e.g. 512x512 px, 10000x10000 px). I observed that incrementing the number of the pixels assigned to each thread increments the performance, so it's better than compute one pixel per thread. The problem is, how can I determine the number of pixels to assign to each thread statically? Computing tests with every possible number? I know that on the GTX 480, 1536 is the maximum number of resident threads per multiprocessor. Have I to consider this number? The following, is the code executed by the kernel.

```
for(i = ((gridDim.x + blockIdx.x) * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x; i < width * height; i += (gridDim.x * blockDim.x)) {
    float grayPix = 0.0f;
    float r = static_cast< float >(inputImage[i]);
    float g = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(width * height) + i]);
    float b = static_cast< float >(inputImage[(2 * width * height) + i]);

    grayPix = ((0.3f * r) + (0.59f * g) + (0.11f * b));
    grayPix = (grayPix * 0.6f) + 0.5f;
    darkGrayImage[i] = static_cast< unsigned char >(grayPix);
}
```

Comment: The performance depends on many factors: Register usage, memory coalescing, and of course the block- and grid size. You might gain some information by entering your numbers into the "NVIDIA CUDA Occupancy Calculator" - this is an XLS (Excel) file available at http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls

Comment: @Marco: It isn't even necessary to use the occupancy spreadsheet any more. The runtime API features `cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor` which will do all the hard work for you

Comment: @talonmies Right, that was added in ... CUDA 6 or so? However, I think the spreadsheet can still be handier for a quick check than writing custom code, consulting the API docs and trying out different parametrizations in some modify-compile-run-repeat-cycle. I just wanted to mention it (although I haven't used it extensively myself, and can't say how helpful it really is for a targeted optimization)

Comment: @Marco: I've already tried the "NVIDIA CUDA Occupancy Calculator". But the only thing that I can see is the impact of varying 1) register count per thread, 2) shared memory per block and  3)block size. There are no suggestions regarding the best amount of blocks to use to gain performance. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sooo familiar with it either, so I think @talonmies may give more focussed advice here. But for example, when you open the XLS with default settings, and then change the "Threads per Block" to 128, you will see that the occupancy (in the upper chart, and in the field "Occupancy of each Multiprocessor") *decreases*. The maxima seem to be achieved e.g. for 512 or 672 threads (100% or 98% occupancy)

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is, how can I determine the number of pixels to assign to each thread statically? Computing tests with every possible number?

Although you haven't shown any code, you've mentioned an observed characteristic:

> I observed that incrementing the number of the pixels assigned to each thread increments the performance,

This is actually a fairly common observation for these types of workloads, and it may also be the case that this is more evident on Fermi than on newer architectures.  A similar observation occurs during matrix transpose.  If you write a "naive" matrix transpose that transposes one element per thread, and compare it with the matrix transpose discussed [here](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/) that transposes multiple elements per thread, you will discover, especially on Fermi, that the multiple element per thread transpose can achieve approximately the available memory bandwidth on the device, whereas the one-element-per-thread transpose cannot.  This ultimately has to do with the ability of the machine to hide *latency*, and the ability of your code to expose enough work to allow the machine to hide latency.  Understanding the underlying behavior is somewhat involved, but fortunately, the optimization objective is fairly simple.

GPUs hide latency by having lots of available work to switch to, when they are waiting on previously issued operations to complete.   So if I have a lot of memory traffic, the individual requests to memory have a long latency associated with them.  If I have other work that the machine can do while it is waiting for the memory traffic to return data (even if that work generates more memory traffic), then the machine can use that work to keep itself busy and hide latency.

The way to give the machine lots of work starts by making sure that we have enabled the maximum number of warps that can fit within the machine's instantaneous capacity.  This number is fairly simple to compute, it is the product of the number of SMs on your GPU and the maximum number of warps that can be resident on each SM. We want to launch a kernel that meets or exceeds this number, but additional warps/blocks beyond this number *don't necessarily* help us hide latency.

Once we have met the above number, we want to pack as much "work" as possible into each thread.  Effectively, for the problem you describe and the matrix transpose case, packing as much work into each thread means handling multiple elements per thread.

So the steps are fairly simple:

1. Launch as many warps as the machine can handle instantaneously
2. Put all remaining work in the thread code, if possible.

Let's take a simplistic example.  Suppose my GPU has 2 SMs, each of which can handle 4 warps (128 threads).  Note that this is *not* the number of cores, but the "Maximum number of resident warps per multiprocessor" as indicated by the deviceQuery output.

My objective then is to create a grid of 8 warps, i.e. 256 threads total (in at least 2 threadblocks, so they can distribute to each of the 2 SMs) and make those warps perform the entire problem by handling multiple elements per thread.  So if my overall problem space is a total of 1024x1024 elements, I would ideally want to handle 1024*1024/256 elements per thread.

Note that this method gives us an optimization *direction*.  We do not necessarily have to achieve this objective completely in order to saturate the machine.  It might be the case that it is only necessary, for example, to handle 8 elements per thread, in order to allow the machine to fully hide latency, and usually another limiting factor will appear, as discussed below.

Following this method will tend to remove *latency* as a limiting factor for performance of your kernel.  Using the profiler, you can assess the extent to which latency is a limiting factor in a number of ways, but a fairly simple one is to capture the `sm_efficiency` [metric](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference), and perhaps compare that metric in the two cases you have outlined (one element per thread, multiple elements per thread).  I suspect you will find, for your code, that the `sm_efficiency` metric indicates a higher efficiency in the multiple elements per thread case, and this is indicating that latency is less of a limiting factor in that case.

Once you remove latency as a limiting factor, you will tend to run into one of the other two machine limiting factors for performance: compute throughput and memory throughput (bandwidth).  In the matrix transpose case, once we have sufficiently dealt with the latency issue, then the kernel tends to run at a speed limited by memory bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and detailed reply! So, to check if I correctly understood, with an image of 10200x6500 px (66300000 px), 15 SM and 48 maximum number of resident warps per multiprocessor. I have 15x48x32= 23040 threads that can be resident at the time. 66300000/23040=2877.60, that means 2878 pixel per thread. Right?

Comment: Yes, however it's likely that the point at which you will have removed latency from the situation is far less than 2878 pixels per thread.  Furthermore, in your real example, you'll probably want to choose a threadblock size of 512 threads per block, with the objective of having 3 threadblocks resident per SM, to achieve the 1536 threads (48 warps) resident goal.  So you'd launch a kernel of 45 threadblocks, each with 512 threads per block.

Comment: Finally, since you haven't shown any code, just be aware that exposing work at the thread level in this way depends on the compiler being able to move independent operations around.

Comment: I thought this answer to be particularly well written!

Comment: I tried your approach, with 'dim3 gridSize(45);  dim3 blockSize(512);' . But using a square grid of size: 'unsigned int grid_size = static_cast< unsigned int >(ceil(sqrt(ceil(width * height / PX_TH) / (float)256)))' where PX_TH is the number of pixels to assign to each thread, and blocks of 256, I obtain more performance. In the kernel, in a for I read the R-G-B values for each pixel, I calculate the gray value and I store the new pixel. Finally, I increment the index of the pixel to compute. E.g. 65536000 px, 1st approach takes 0.004402s, 2nd with 11 px per thread takes 0.003255s. Any idea?

Comment: 1. you haven't shown any code  2. so far as I can tell, that is not a "square grid"  3. I indicated in my answer that a relatively small number of pixels per thread might be suitable/preferable 4. I indicated in the comments that packing work into a thread is dependent on the compiler's ability to reorder operations.  This might well be facilitated (e.g. loop unrolling) by having a relatively small loop, rather than a huge one.  I was trying to give some guidance in my answer.  But any optimization effort probably must consider multiple factors, and the actual code, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Careful, comparative use of the profiler between the two cases may shed some light on why one case seems to work better than the other.  Key metrics might be memory metrics such as `gld_efficiency` and also the previously mentioned `sm_efficiency`.  This may give some indication of the underlying difference between the two cases.  For example, if the method by which you assign pixels to threads differs in an important way between the two methods (e.g. one coalesces nicely, the other does not) then that would overshadow any latency/efficiency differences probably.

Comment: "Finally, I increment the index of the pixel to compute"  This worries me.  If  by "increment" you mean +1 on index or something like that, you're doing it wrong and niether case will generate coalesced memory access.  In that case, I *would* expect the 11 pixels per thread to work better than  a large number per thread, because the pixels that are being accessed by adjacent threads will be much closer to each other, which will lead to a better memory access scenario (even though still not properly/fully coalesced.)

Comment: I've added  the code of the kernel. I think I'm accessing the memory in a coalesced way. By the way, usign a square grid, 
'dim3 gridSize(grid_size, grid_size);' and blocks of 256 threads: 'dim3 blockSize(256);' I obtain better results fixing the number of threads. But as you can image, it should be better to select the "best" number of thread that should be calculable.

Comment: For the suggested implementation, the gld_efficiency is 24.71%, while for the actual implementation is 24.99%.  The sm_efficiency is 94.84%, for the suggested implementation and 99.81% for the actual. The application was analyzed with a 66300000 px image. The actual implementation assigns as default 11 px per thread.

Comment: The code that you have now shown could not make sensible use of a square grid (`dim3 gridSize(grid_size, grid_size)`) -- there is no use of any `.y` grid variables, for example.  I don't think it makes sense to continue this any further unless you want to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).